# Recommending products to buy

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, keras, predictive-modeling

I have the following dataset where each row represents a customer, and each column is a product. So for example, the first customer (row 0) buys product 2 and product 7. The second customer (row 1) buys products 3,6 and 7. And so on...

Basically I want to recommend customers who are already buying certain products, some other products. Here is an example:

Let's say I choose all customers who are buying products 1 and 4. How would I recommend them the next best...let's say 3... products based on what other 1 and 4 customers are buying?

I'd like to use keras neural networks or random forests for this kind of task. Thanks :)

---

product 1.......product 2.........product 3....... product 4...... product 5........ product 6..... product 7

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic case of recommendation problem.
There are a couple of steps in which a recommendation is made:

1. Candidate Generation - What to show to a customer?
2. Candidate Ranking - How to show the items to the customer?
3. Personalisation - How to show the items to each customer?

**Step 1** and **2** are general that means they talk about the overall trend and customer base, meaning we perform these steps by saying in general what would happen.

**Step 3** is more personalised, where the ranking (order) in which the items are shown can be different for different customers.

For starters you should experiment with **Singular Value Decomposition** and **Matrix Factorisation** for recommendation.

If you have already tried your hand at these, then you should go with **word2vec** or **doc2vec** for building the step 1 and 2 and some kind of neural network at the end that ties to it in the end.

Comment: Thanks Kaustubh. At this stage, I actually just want to get a single output, like people buying products 1 and 2 -> probabilities that they will buy 3,4,5,6,7, and then say, recommend them the highest 3 probabilities.